# Raspberry Pi and bluetooth audio

Tags: python, audio, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3, pulseaudio

I am not sure why this is so difficult to find exactly what I want online, but I am looking for a way to send the my phone's/computer's audio to the raspberry pi via bluetooth and then output it to headphone jack. I have been able to write a python script to connect devices to the pi and they connected successfully. What I am not understanding is how to take the audio that is sent to the pi and output it to the headphone jack. Is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: You need a bluetooth audio profile and which profile depends on what audio you want to receive. If you want to receive audio calls on RPI, you need bluetooth HFP profile running in HF role and pulseaudio on RPI. You can try ofono for HFP profile or check test/test-hfp python script in bluez source directory.

Comment: Is there documentation of this process? Also, I want the pi to receive music audio and call audio.